# commentThreads().list returns information from about 5 months

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Good day,

commentThreads().list returns information from about 5 months, something is wrong or the API returns filtering?

another query: I see that it returns me in chronological order from the most recent first, is this so?

can this api return all the comments from all the years that a youtube channel exists?

I appreciate any answer

Comment: Concerning *commentThreads().list returns information from about 5 months, something is wrong or the API returns filtering?*, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Probably working as intended